# Cannot Hash Password in Cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have created a registration form by following this tutorial https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html, but the password is saving in the database without encryption as plain text. Please help to sort out my issue.
Here is my code:

> Add.ctp

```
<h1>Register new user </h1>


<div class="users form">
<?= $this->Form->create($user) ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Add User') ?></legend>
        <?= $this->Form->control('username') ?>
        <?= $this->Form->control('password') ?>

   </fieldset>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')); ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

> Entity/User.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Entity;

use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;
use Cake\ORM\Entity;

class User extends Entity
{

    // Make all fields mass assignable except for primary key field "id".
 // Make all fields mass assignable for now.
protected $_accessible = ['*' => true];

protected function _setPassword($password) {
    return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
}

    // ...
}

?>
```

> UsersTable.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;
use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;

class UsersTable extends Table
{
   public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
        return $validator
        ->notEmpty('username', 'A username is required')
        ->notEmpty('password', 'A password is required');

    }


}

?>
```

> UsersController.php

```
<?php

namespace PanelAdmin\Controller;

use Cake\Controller\Controller;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\Event\Event;

class UsersController extends AppController

{

 public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);
        $this->Auth->allow('add');
    }

     public function index()
     {
        $this->set('users', $this->Users->find('all'));
    }

    public function view($id)
    {
        $user = $this->Users->get($id);
        $this->set(compact('user'));
    }

    public function add()
    {
        $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            // Prior to 3.4.0 $this->request->data() was used.
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->getData());
            //debug($user); die;
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'add']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add the user.'));
        }
        $this->set('user', $user);
    }

    }

?>
```

Directory Structure:
[image]

Comment: Your code seems good, are you sure you've uploaded the updated files and removed the cache files?

Comment: @Ofir Baruch: Yes i'm sure. I think my model file are not getting called because if i debug it it makes no difference, nothing prints.

Comment: checked this link https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/3863 but nothing works

Comment: And you have a DB table named Users, right?

Comment: yes: It is users.

Comment: Share your files directories, If the entity isn't been called I believe it's because of naming.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159329/discussion-between-user3653474-and-ofir-baruch).

Comment: I have added image of Directory Structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either your namespaces are wrong, or you've put the code in the wrong place. If the code is supposed to live inside the `PanelAdmin` plugin, then you shouldn't use the `App` namespace for your model/entity classes, but the `PanelAdmin` one.